# Multiple Flash Player Instances?

Tags: vb.net, flash, video-streaming

Greeting! I have an application Written in VB.net that uses Flash Player 10r45. My customers keep automatically updating flash player to the latest version of flash which effectively breaks this legacy application. Is there a way to install two separate version of Flash? Reprogramming large amounts of the application is not an option because of the age of the software, nor would it be profitable do more than a few day fix.

I can provide more details and go deeper into the code if needed, but I'm betting a short answer will be my answer.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you use Flash. If it is a browser, I would have a different suggestion than if your app uses it to show instructions or so.

Edit: There is no "easy" way to have multiple Flash versions installed.

Comment: The app is a client based app that runs on Windows XP and 7 and One day I hope 8.  It uses Flash to render a video I believe.